# Css: Styling footer with a body height=100%

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an angularJS web app with a simple template like:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />        
      </head>
    <body id="top">

      <!-- Templates with views will be inserted here -->
      <div class="wrapper" ng-view>
        <div class="language-loaded">    
          <div class="home-top">
            <div class="title-wrapper">
                <h1 class="home-title">Title</h1>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- This is the footer template -->
    <div ng-include src="'partials/footer.html'">          
      <footer id="footer">
        This is the footer
      </footer>
    </div>
```

The resulting web page is like:

HTML:

```
  <body id="top">
    <div class="wrapper">

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .wrapper, .language-loaded, .home-top {height: 100%}
body {  background-color: #F5F5F5}
.home-top {background-color: blue;}
.title-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 39%;
    color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

As you can see I have a height:100% in some components because I want the home page opens a background image that takes the 100% of the height. Below this image there is some main content. The point is that with this structure, the footer is displayed just below the background image, over the main content.

Please see this plunker to see the problem more clearly: https://plnkr.co/edit/gyNOJmc5uzHAEhXwzRuq?p=preview

What I would like is to place the footer at the end of the page, as expected, below the whole main content.

Comment: well if .wrapper has height:100% there's no room for the #footer unless you want overlap the two

Comment: Ok. But how should I do it to get everything working?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `<div>` around the `<footer>`?

Comment: Note it´s an AngularJS template: so that div is from: <div ng-include src="'partials/footer.html'"></div> and inside it goes the footer. But, I think that does not go to the point of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div><p>content</p>...</div>` is outside `.home-top` which has `height: 100%` and within `.language-loaded` which has 100% too. So basically you have content *overflowing* `.language-loaded`.

If you can't change the HTML structure, then remove all the `height: 100%` and just use `height: 100vh` ([viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)) on `.home-top`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F5F5F5
}

.home-top {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.title-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 39%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="top">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div ng-show="languageLoaded" class="language-loaded">
      <div class="home-top">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
          <h1 class="home-title">Title</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <footer id="footer" style="background-color: red">
      This is the footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I´m afraid that is not working. As you can see the content in over the title, also over the background-image (to simplify background color). home-top should have a background image in this case a background-color that takes the 100%, but the content should not be inside it, but below. And the footer at the bottom of all.

Comment: @Rober sorry, I didn't understand the question correctly. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I understand your point and that would be great. But I´m afraid it´s not that easy. Sorry if I didn´t explain myself. I have updated the problem. I don´t know if you know AngularJS, the content is loaded dinamically inside ng-view whenever the view changes. So, in this case, the <div> with content goes inside the wrapper.

Comment: The approach should be something like be able to put the home-top to a height=100% without the need to extend it to all the parent elements. Is this possible?

Comment: @Rober see my new edit. I didn't change the HTML, just the CSS.

Comment: Wow. It´s that easy! I didn´t know about vh. It´s great. Thanks!